# selecting a specific object in a list of objects in a mongodb document in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Here's an example of my mongodb document:

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5e74b430bb7774726c2ea20b"},
"company_name":"Jones and Tillman Associates",
"contact_person_name":"Zeph Sheppard change",
"contact_phone":"+1 (577) 347-4188",
"registration_no":"501",
"front_end_url":"Qui ea dolor dolor l",
"back_end_url":"Cupiditate ex quia a",
"database_id":"5e745fd91c9d44000073a1f3",
"updated_at": {"$date":
    {"$numberLong":"1584941961110"}
},
"created_at":{"$date":
    {"$numberLong":"1584706608160"}
},
"applications":[
    {
        "app_id ":{"$oid":"5e7b281b6ae7250621401672"},
        "name":"Tillman",
        "phone":"9812139775"
    },
    {
        "app_id":{"$oid":"5e7b281b6ae7250621401674"},
        "name":"Jones",
        "phone":"9712115119"
    }
]
}
```

I want to get the application object with a specific 'app_id' from the list applications so I can edit/delete it. I am using jenssegers/mongodb for the laravel Model. This may be trivial but I am new to mongodb and I can't even find it in the jenssegers/laravel-mongodb documentation. Thanks

Comment: Documentation: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: @Sehdev thanks but I cant find the solution in the doc.